# AWS glue Workers vs Concurrency

Tags: aws-glue

I am looking for suggestions on how to set glue job parameters.
Currently I get "Concurrent runs exceeded"as exception.

What can i do to scale and run the job properly

Answer (score 0):

`Concurrent runs exceeded` means that you tried to run the job while an instance of the job is already running and you set the `MaxConcurrentRuns` property of the job. You can scale a job not only by running it concurrently, which I also would advise to, since this most of the Databases / Filesystems you are reading and writing to and from are probably not ACID compliant, you can also increase the `NumberOfWorkers` to deploy additional executor nodes.